# pageinit code executing fine but elements do not update with content and click events do not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Original loading of the page seems to work fine.  Navigating from another page back to the .index page has the issue.  The pageinit code executes fine, all values are calculated fine in the calculate method.  However elements are not updated and click event is broken.  Change events no longer fires when values change.

index.js file

```
$(document).on("pageinit", ".index", function () {
    getElement("btnCalculate").addEventListener("click", calculate, false);    

    $("#txbGrossIncome").change(function () {
        store.set("grossIncome", getElement("txbGrossIncome").value);
    });

    $("#txbTaxRate").change(function () {
        store.set("taxRate", getElement("txbTaxRate").value);
    });

    calculate();    
});

function calculate() {
    var grossIncome = parseFloat(store.get("grossIncome"));
    var taxRate = parseFloat(store.get("taxRate"));

    if (grossIncome) {
        getElement("txbGrossIncome").value = grossIncome;
    }
    else {
        grossIncome = parseFloat(getElement("txbGrossIncome").getAttribute("placeholder"));
    }

    if (taxRate) {
        getElement("txbTaxRate").value = taxRate;
    }
    else {
        taxRate =   parseFloat(getElement("txbTaxRate").getAttribute("placeholder"));
    }

    var netIncome = grossIncome - (grossIncome * (taxRate / 100))
    var totalExpenses = calcExpenses();
    var totalBudget = calcBudget(netIncome, totalExpenses);

    getElement("txtTotalExpenses").innerHTML = "$" + totalExpenses.toFixed(2);
    getElement("txtBudget").innerHTML = "$" + (totalBudget / 12).toFixed(2);
}
```

I'm not sure what is causing this behavior.  Any ideas?  I can send a private link to where this is hosted if necessary to observe the behavior.

Comment: Have you tried to use $(document).ready() instead of $(document).on("pageinit", ".index")?

Comment: If you add your page content dynamically, then better use $(document).on("change", "#txbTaxRate", function () { } instead of $("#txbTaxRate").change(function () {}

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a try.

Comment: However, I should probably add that the code I have now works if I go to the page in the browser and then click the refresh button.  Not sure if it has something to do with how it's getting loaded from the web server.